# C: read txt file, redirect + append to new files by case

Tags: c, operating-system, io-redirection

I have an input txt file, where every 3rd line (the "instruction" line) is at most 4 bytes, and the next two lines (the "data" lines) are each at most 16 bytes.

If the last character in the instruction line is a letter, I want to copy that line as well the next 2 data lines to a newly created file, "letter_in.tmp". If the last characteris a number, I want to only copy that instruction line to a file "number_in.tmp", but skip the 2 data lines.

I'd like to do this using redirection if possible, though it isn't necessary. 
Here is what I wrote:

```
#define LETTER "letter_in.tmp"
#define NUMBER "number_in.tmp"
#define BUFSIZE 17

//argv[1] will be inputFile.txt
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
        usage_err(argc);

    int sav_stdin = dup(0);
    int sav_stdout = dup(1);

    redirect_files(argv[1]);

    return 0;
}


void redirect_files(char* inputF)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen(inputF, "r");

    char buffer[BUFSIZE];
    int fd_LetterIn = open_file(LETTER);
    int fd_NumberIn = open_file(NUMBER);

    //fdopen(fd_LetterIn, "a");
    //fdopen(fd_NumberIn, "a"); 

    unsigned char lastChar;

    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != NULL) 
    {
        lastChar = isLetter(buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1]);
        if (lastChar == 1) //last character is a letter, so copy 3 lines to "letter_in.tmp"
        {
            dup2(fd_LetterIn, 1);
            lseek(fd_LetterIn, 0, SEEK_END);
            puts(buffer);
            fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp);
            puts(buffer);
            fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp);
            puts(buffer);
        }

        else
        {
            dup2(fd_NumberIn, 1);
            lseek(fd_NumberIn, 0, SEEK_END);
            write(fd_NumberIn, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp);
            fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp);
        }
    }
}

int open_file(char* name)
{
    int fd;
    fd = open(name, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if (fd < 0)  // open failed
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: open \"%s\" failed (%d). Exiting\n", name, fd);
        exit(2);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "opened file %s, file descriptor is: %d\n", name, fd);
    return(fd);
}
```

Sample input *inputFile.txt*:

```
3da
000a050a0a050a00
0000000005000005
1de
000a050a0a050a00
000005fb0002fb05
3e2
ec0af60a000000f6
f6ececece2f6e200
362
f600fbfb00fb0a00
0a05000afb0af605
195a
00f6fbf6f6fbf600
00000000fb0000fb
```

This is what I actually ended up with:

[image]

[image]

1) Why is everything only being written to *number_in.tmp*?

2) Why are the copied lines being mixed together, and not cleanly printing on a new line? Shouldn't `fgets` and *puts* work for reading/writing 1 line at a time? Especially since I know what the max length of each line is. (I also tried using `scanf()`, `printf()`, `write()`, but none of those made a difference).

3) If I were to successfully use `fdopen(, "a")`, I wouldn't need to use `dup2` and `lseek`, correct?

4) Suppose from within  `redirect_files()`, I redirect the standard input/output to some file, but don't change it back when the function ends. When I jump back to `main()`, is standard input/output still pointing to the redirected files, or is it the same as before `redirect_files()` was called?

Answer (score 0):

You are always passing `\n` to `isLetter` function, note that `fgets` appends `\n` to buffer.

```
    lastChar = isLetter(buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1]);
```

should be

```
    lastChar = isLetter(buffer[strlen(buffer) - 2]); //Add boundary checks.
```

---

And while writing you should use `strlen` not `sizeof`, otherwise you end up writing junk.

```
        write(fd_NumberIn, buffer, strlen(buffer));
```